# Search Center URL issue

Tags: 2013, search, search-configuration

I've got a Search Center configured. When I'm choosing to use that alternative from another site collection in SharePoint my url gets a bit messed up.

In Central Admin the Search Center URL is configured to: `http://sharepoint/sites/site/`

- What I want: `http://sharepoint/sites/site/results.aspx?k=searchContentText`
- What I get: `http://sharepoint/sites/site/default.aspx/results.aspx?k=searchContentText`

When I navigate to the search center I of course come to the welcome page, default.aspx and if i search from the defult.aspx (search center) my result page is displayed with the results. But if I get sent there with the faulty url i can't even redo the search to get to the result.aspx page.

What can be causing this issue? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

So I solved the issue and thought someone might find this useful if they encounter the same issue.

I created an empty Wikipages library on the search center and changed the configuration to that url.

Before: `http://sharepoint/sites/site/`

After: `http://sharepoint/sites/site/pages`

That solved the issue, now the search works great.